# How can I define a non-python repository as a dependency for my python package?

Tags: python, git, conda

I'm working on a python package that needs to pull in some CSS files from a separate git repository. Currently I'm defining the CSS repo as a submodule of the python repo, but git submodules are, frankly, a bit of a pain to work with. Instead, is there a way to define the CSS repo as a dependency for pip or conda?

Ideally, I would like to be able to add something like this to my conda environment.yml file:

```
external_dependencies:
  - git+https://github.com/example/css-repo.git
```

and have that repo cloned to a known location. Note that the CSS repo has no python code, so can't just be listed as a normal python dependency.

I haven't been able to find any documentation on this, but surely other people must have faced the same problem. Is there an elegant solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. `pip/setuptools/wheel` works with Python code or C/C++ that compile to binary extensions. Everything else is *data* and should be incorporated into a distribution package as [data](https://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#distutils-additional-files). Please note also you must not install data files into known locations because you should consider the difference between global installation, user (`pip install --user`) and virtual environments (`virtualenv` and `venv`).

If you need something bigger and more clever than that you should consider system packages (`rpm`, `apt/deb`, etc.)

Comment: To reframe the question then, can data be specified using external files? Or only from files already in the directory tree? In other words, is there something like this:

`setup(...,
      data_files=[('bitmaps', ['https://path.to/bm/b1.gif', 'https://path.to/bm/b2.gif']),
                  ('config', ['https://path.to/cfg/data.cfg'])],
     )`

Comment: No. Only local files. Could be drawn from an already fetched submodule.